# iOS SchemeScriptAction "cp: path. is not a directory"

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode15

I haven't opened my iOS project in a while, but I'm getting some fishy behavior I can't seem to pin down... the typical cryptic Xcode build garbage.

I'm using `XCode 15.0.1 (15A507)`, last time I opened this project was probably `XCode 13` or earlier and it was building and running at that point.

Here's the error: `cp: path. is not a directory`

[image: error cp: path. is not a directory]

What I've already done to troubleshoot:

1. Browse to the directory `/var/folders/0f/54ys1wbd3k543ks27vnjpww00000gn/T/` and looking for `SchemeScriptAction-cNhrWM.sh` to see what it looks like. This file doesn't exist. It must be a temp file generated for the build and deleted afterwards.
2. I've tried removing all of the pre-build scripts entirely. This didn't fix the issue.
3. Tried clearing DerivedData folder and cleaning the build folder.

Thanks for any help or suggestions for troubleshooting! Including information about SchemeScriptAction, how this is generated, where it comes from and where to look in the project given that there is obviously an issue with how this temporary script is generated.